# cant make selenium find element

Tags: python, html, reactjs, selenium

I tried to make selenium find an element (1 of the listing below) on this [site](https://opensea.io/collection/mekaverse?tab=activity&search%5BisSingleCollection%5D=true&search%5BeventTypes%5D%5B0%5D=AUCTION_CREATED) by xpath :

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get(url)
driver.execute_script('window.scrollBy(0, 2000)')
folder = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="__next"]/div[1]/main/div/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[15]/button/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/span[2]/a')
print(folder)
```

but I get an error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="__next"]/div[1]/main/div/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[15]/button/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/span[2]/a"}
```

I know the site made by react, but I didn't manage to get the element.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

why don't use xpath feature?

```
//div[@role='listitem']//a[contains(@href,'assets')]
```

right click on node and click on *copy xpath* is not usefull, you must search in elements with xpath query

```
folder = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@role='listitem']//a[contains(@href,'assets')]")
```

before search with xpath check that all elements in page has been loaded ([wait.until](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html))

Comment: Thanks, it worked (after adding a time.sleep of 2 seconds :) ) !
Do you think using selenium is the best way of getting information from this site?

Comment: Also don't use time.sleep and use webdriver waits.

Answer (score 0):

From PersianMans's answer combined with webdriver waits you can make your program wait for the element to be there. Etc 10 seconds as such.

```
wait=WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
url="https://opensea.io/collection/mekaverse?tab=activity&search%5BisSingleCollection%5D=true&search%5BeventTypes%5D%5B0%5D=AUCTION_CREATED"
driver.get(url)
folder=wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//div[@role='listitem']//a[contains(@href,'assets')]")))
print(folder)
```

Import

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```